# For paths, the "getNumberOfTransporters" function throws an exception

Tags: anylogic

I created a very simple network with some nodes and a few paths. A limited amount of agents (peoples) now were supposed to just get from A to B and back in a loop. Worked so far.

Next, I wanted to limit the number of agents that can be at the same time on a specific path, using the "limit number of transporters" option in the general section of a path. This did not work. When I wanted to know how many transporters are on the path anyway, I tried calling (and displaying the output) of various functions like "getNumberOfTransporters()", "getTransporters()", etc. (called by "pathname.functionname()", each resulting in an exception, which usually looked like this:

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.anylogic.engine.markup.Path.getNumberOfTransporters(Unknown Source)
    at movetest.Main.executeActionOf(Main.java:141)
    at com.anylogic.engine.EventTimeout.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.gc(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$i.run(Unknown Source)
```

The function "getMaxNumberOfTransporters()" did work though, which simply outputted the number that was specified in the "limit number of transporters" option field.

So the question is: Why is this exception being thrown? Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug with Anylogic regarding these transporter-related functions/functionality?

By the way, I'm using AnyLogic 8 Personal Learning Edition 8.3.2 on a 64-bit Windows 10 computer.

Comment: Without seeing entire code, it is impossible to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since AnyLogic Paths provide these methods (`getNumberOfTransporters`, etc.) this is definitely a bug; these methods should not be throwing internal exceptions under any circumstances.

A quick test confirms that these methods throw this exception if **there is no transporter fleet in your model** (so exceptions being thrown is a little more forgiveable). The exceptions *aren't* thrown if you have a fleet with a home location set, even if that location is in a different network to the path you are checking; i.e., even if it is never possible for any transporters to be on that path. (If you don't set a home location for the fleet you get a different exception relating to that.)

So it looks like you are trying to use normal moving resource agents (i.e., from the Process Modeling library) as your 'transporters' instead of the Material Handling library transporter fleet.

If you want to restrict 'transported' movement around your network, you have two options which are conceptually different:

1. Use Process Modeling resource pools (as you are doing) and *control the movement inside the Process Modeling blocks* via use of things like `RestrictedAreaStart` and `RestrictedAreaEnd` blocks (i.e., you break the movement down into the relevant segments and control flow through the blocks that control the relevant portions). See the Job Shop example model for a good (and complex) example of this. Note that, conceptually, **space markup only gives you distances for use in the model (not any model behaviour)**. This is the norm: space markup is only there to visualise your model and provide distances. (It also controls what movements are valid since there needs to be a route through the network but it's normally a design error if a required movement is not permitted, so this isn't really model behaviour.)
2. Use a `TransporterFleet` instead. They can interoperate with normal Process Modeling blocks (see screenshot below) and they are designed precisely to support this style of 'control their flow via restrictions on numbers of transporters on paths' (plus have built-in functionality for load/unload times, behaviour after dropping off, etc.). Notice that conceptually with the Materials Handling library **the space markup defines model behaviour** (rather than just giving you distances and visualisation). This is a major conceptual departure with the Materials Handling library. (Similarly, the conveyer networks you define using Materials Handling space markup also define model behaviour; e.g., the `Station` elements therein are similar to `Service` blocks in the Process Modeling library.)

[image: simple transporter usage in a DES]

P.S. I meant to add that, unless you use a transporter fleet, there *is* no direct way of getting which agents are on which paths. The closest is that networks support the `getNearestPath` function (see the API reference for `Network` in the help), one flavour of which will give you the nearest `Path` to an agent. (So, by looping through all resource agents and checking this for each of them, you could obliquely determine how many are 'on' each path, though you have to be careful because this only gives the *nearest* `Path`.) But this is irrelevant for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Exactly, I'm using regular agents from the process modeling library. I'm pretty much a beginner and the idea was just to make a simple network with various connections and let the agents move from one node to another and back and see what optimal path they take. Wanted to make it a little harder for them by adding restrictions like speed limits and maximum number of agents that can be on a certain path at the same time.

Do you by chance know if there is an easy way to check how many agents there currently are on a specific path?

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer to reflect your wider questions. You should probably edit your main question to make clearer what you are asking.