# Agents crossing Path ( discrete event modelling)

Tags: anylogic

I'm tring to count how many agents have crossed a particular path. I've seen this done with transporter and I've seen other question with nodes. But i want to count specifically how many agents passed through a path.
Any suggestion is really appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easily possible.

Either you ["agentify" your network](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiGJP0k1miFbQ0XfchiMK9nxj-qr42dyw) (not trivial). Or you switch to transporters.

Last option: You could use the `getNearestAgent()` function but that is also not an elegant solution, see [For paths, the "getNumberOfTransporters" function throws an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397046/for-paths-the-getnumberoftransporters-function-throws-an-exception?rq=2)